# Insert text with right adjustment of margin in PDFLIB

Tags: php, pdflib

I use PDFLib7 with PHP 7, and I need to insert text with the margin adjusted to the right (as: "text-align: center;" in CSS), instead the default left margin adjustment.

This tasks seems to be a little tougher than expected. Pls. see the code I use to add text-field to my pdf-document.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

/Martin

```
    PDF_setfont($p, $font2, 10.0);
    PDF_set_text_pos($p, 350, 730);
    PDF_show($p, "$d_ordreinfo");
```